# Laravel Object not found Error 404

Tags: laravel, object, url, http-status-code-404, laravel-5.1

The laravel project runs at another system with a fixed ip.

If I access the project on another computer via this line:

> http://61.211.45.158/appi/public/auth/login

(changed to original ip for privacy)

it works so far but if I login the url does change to this:

> http://61.211.45.158/auth/login

and I get the error

> Object not found ... 404

The laravel project works if I call it locally via localhost....

I do not know why this is happening really big thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I removed the authentification and somehow it show the page now just without the login and register, does anyone know why?

I commented this line:

> ## Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function ()
>
> ## {

Comment: have you configured a .htacess file ?

Comment: How are you linking to the login page?

Comment: hmm what do I have to configure in a .htacess file ( I think I did not)

Comment: I actually am linking to 'home'

Comment: Locally this: http://localhost:8000/home

Comment: Do not edit `.htaccess`. What web server do you use on a remote server (Apache or Nginx)?

Comment: Apache, ok I did not edit it for sure

Comment: I've updated my answer with settings for Apache, please look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong web server configuration on the remote machine. Web server should be pointed to a `public` directory, for example `/home/someuser/appi/public`, but not to `/home/someuser/`. Edit Apache config file (do not edit `.htaccess`), you should have similar lines in it:

```
DocumentRoot "/path_to_appi/appi/public"
<Directory "/path_to_appi/appi/public">
```

Then restart Apache to make everything work.

Comment: Nice this worked thanks a lot (I copied in the full directory "C..../appi/public"